# How to detect vowels in a string and if a specific letter is beside a vowel, it is also considered a string?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

Working on a function that would detect if there are any vowels in a given string, also checks if the letter "g" is beside the vowels or not. If the letter "g" is beside a vowel, then it will also be considered a vowel. I did post a question similar to this and got an answer that almost works but I got no explanation as to how it was done and no-one replied to my comment asking for clarification.

Here is the function:

```
    import re


def disemvowel(text):
    result = re.sub(r"G[AEIOU]+|[AEIOU]+G|[AEIOU]+", "", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    print(result)


disemvowel("fragrance")
# frrnc

disemvowel('gargden')
# rgdn

disemvowel('gargdenag')
# rgdn
```

This function works for most cases except for when the letter 'g' both precedes and exceeds a vowel. For example, it does not work when I input 'gag' it returns 'g' when it isn't supposed to return anything. I just need clarification as to how this function works and what edits I could make to it to have it run properly for all scenarios.

This is my original function that I worked on but it only works for vowels since I could not figure out how to add a condition where it would detect the letter 'g' beside a vowel:

```
def disemvowel(text):
text = list(text)
new_letters = []
for i in text:
    if i.lower() == "a" or i.lower() == "e" or i.lower() == "i" or i.lower() == "o" or i.lower() == "u":
        pass
    else:
        new_letters.append(i)
print (''.join(new_letters))

disemvowel('fragrance')
# frgrnc
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of doing it.

```
import re
def methodA(txt,ii):

    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
    txt = re.sub('g'+ vowels[ii] +'g' ,' ', txt) # remove strings like gug
    txt = re.sub(vowels[ii] + 'g', ' ', txt) # remove strings like ug
    txt = re.sub('g' + vowels[ii] , ' ', txt) # remove strings like gu

    if (ii == len(vowels)-1 or txt == '' or txt == ' ') : # if string is empty or all vowels have been used
        txt = "".join( list(filter(lambda x:x not in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'], list(txt)))) # finally remove all vowels
        txt = re.sub(' ', '', txt)
        return txt
    ii = ii + 1
    return methodA(txt, ii) # call the function with next vowel in the list
```

ans = methodA("fragrance",0) # initialize with zeroth vowel

#### frrnc

```
from itertools import permutations
def methodB(txt):
    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'] # vowels to remove
    a = [] # store permutation of strings to remove in this list
    for vowel in vowels: # create the list of all combo of characters that need to be removed
        a.extend(list(map(lambda x : x[0]+x[1]+x[2]  , list(permutations('g' + vowel + 'g')) )) )
        a.extend(list(map(lambda x : x[0]+x[1]  , list(permutations('g' + vowel )) )))

    lims = list(set([re.sub('gg','', xx)  for xx in a ])) # we don't need gg and the duplicates
    lims.sort(key = len,reverse = True) # create a list of strings sorted by length
    for ll in lims:
        txt = re.sub(ll, ' ', txt) # remove the required strings with largest ones first
    return re.sub(' ','',txt)
```

ans=methodB("fragrance")

#### frrnc

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for this task:

```
def disemvowel(text):
    return re.sub(r"G?[AEIOU]+G?", "", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)


tests = {"fragrance": "frrnc", "gargden": "rgdn", "gargdenag": "rgdn", "gag": ""}

for test, value in tests.items():
    assert disemvowel(test) == value

print("PASSED")
```